In persistent_bottom_nav_bar , I am using it's style15 And in navbardecoration i have applied borderRadius But it don't take it.I have tried Stack
I want this type of borderRadius. But it doesn't apply BorderRadius.
Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 80,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            PersistentTabView(context,
                screens: pages,
                navBarHeight: 80,
                controller: _controller,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white30,
                navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style15,
                items: myscreens,
                confineInSafeArea: true,
                handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
                resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
                stateManagement: true,
                hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
                decoration: NavBarDecoration(
                    adjustScreenBottomPaddingOnCurve: true,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    colorBehindNavBar: Colors.white),
                popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
                popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,
                itemAnimationProperties: const ItemAnimationProperties(
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), curve: Curves.ease),
                screenTransitionAnimation: const ScreenTransitionAnimation(
                    animateTabTransition: true,
                    curve: Curves.ease,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200))),
          ],
        ),

I have applied this type of code but still it doesn't work It can't apply borderRadius .
Now i am making it customly But still i want the solution .
I have tried by stack , Wrapping it in a container but still doesn't work .

Please share image that you want to create with PersistentTabView.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Om Trivedi do you required this bottom bar with rounded selected tab?
https://prnt.sc/bBpO53lIb9wC

@DroidFlutter No I want give border Radius in whole bottomNavBar which was given in given code but it doesn't seems to apply there .
Which can be solved by using stack but it is not proffesional way .

I have added code for bottomNavBar border radius... hope it helps

For border radius to bottomNavBar use flutter's package persistent_bottom_nav_bar_v2 instead of persistent_bottom_nav_bar
Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        children: [
          PersistentTabView(
            navBarHeight: 80,
            handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
            stateManagement: true,
            popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
            popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,
            screenTransitionAnimation: const ScreenTransitionAnimation(
              curve: Curves.ease,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            ),
            tabs: [
              PersistentTabConfig(
                screen: Container(),
                item: ItemConfig(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  title: "Home",
                ),
              ),
              PersistentTabConfig(
                screen: Container(),
                item: ItemConfig(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.message),
                  title: "Messages",
                ),
              ),
              PersistentTabConfig(
                screen: Container(),
                item: ItemConfig(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                  title: "Settings",
                ),
              ),
            ],
            navBarBuilder: (navBarConfig) => Style1BottomNavBar(
              navBarConfig: navBarConfig,
              navBarDecoration: NavBarDecoration(
                color: Colors.orange,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(50), topRight: Radius.circular(50)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );


This worked for me.
